# Magento Installation on xampp windows 10

Tags: php, fatal-error, magento-2-commerce, gd2, api-functional-tests

I was installing Magento on my pc on xampp. First I had a lot of errors worked through it but now am getting the message below would please advise. Thank you in advance

```
PHP Parse error:  syntax error, unexpected 'protected' (T_PROTECTED) in C:\xampp
\htdocs\magento24\vendor\magento\framework\Image\Adapter\Gd2.php on line 108

Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'protected' (T_PROTECTED) in C:\xampp\htdo
cs\magento24\vendor\magento\framework\Image\Adapter\Gd2.php on line 108
PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Exception: User Error: Some transactions have not bee
n committed or rolled back in C:\xampp\htdocs\magento24\vendor\magento\framework
\DB\Adapter\Pdo\Mysql.php on line 4050 in C:\xampp\htdocs\magento24\vendor\magen
to\framework\App\ErrorHandler.php:61
Stack trace:
#0 [internal function]: Magento\Framework\App\ErrorHandler->handler(256, 'Some t
ransactio...', 'C:\\xampp\\htdocs...', 4050, Array)
#1 C:\xampp\htdocs\magento24\vendor\magento\framework\DB\Adapter\Pdo\Mysql.php(4
050): trigger_error('Some transactio...', 256)
#2 [internal function]: Magento\Framework\DB\Adapter\Pdo\Mysql->__destruct()
#3 {main}
  thrown in C:\xampp\htdocs\magento24\vendor\magento\framework\App\ErrorHandler.
php on line 61

Fatal error: Uncaught Exception: User Error: Some transactions have not been com
mitted or rolled back in C:\xampp\htdocs\magento24\vendor\magento\framework\DB\A
dapter\Pdo\Mysql.php on line 4050 in C:\xampp\htdocs\magento24\vendor\magento\fr
amework\App\ErrorHandler.php:61
Stack trace:
#0 [internal function]: Magento\Framework\App\ErrorHandler->handler(256, 'Some t
ransactio...', 'C:\\xampp\\htdocs...', 4050, Array)
#1 C:\xampp\htdocs\magento24\vendor\magento\framework\DB\Adapter\Pdo\Mysql.php(4
050): trigger_error('Some transactio...', 256)
#2 [internal function]: Magento\Framework\DB\Adapter\Pdo\Mysql->__destruct()
#3 {main}
  thrown in C:\xampp\htdocs\magento24\vendor\magento\framework\App\ErrorHandler.
php on line 61
```

Comment: This error comes when you don't have compatible PHP version. I suggest you go with docker or sub-linux system

Answer (score 0):

I sorted the issue by downgrading to php 7.4 but now I am facing this new one

in compat.php line 1927: this is not implemented, as it is not possible to implement argon2i with acceptable performance in pure-php

am using docker for my axelor erp

thanks